# SXA 1.8 Link field class ignored from rendering variant

Tags: sxa

I have created a link rendering variant and put in css class of "btn login-button"

[image]

However in my markup where the link is using that rendering variant this does not appear

```
<div class="component link member-hub col-12">
    <div class="component-content">
        <a href="/Articles" data-variantfieldname="Link" data-variantitemid="{B7229055-B046-47D3-AAC4-6EA4815F2696}">Login</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way I have gotten it to appear on the anchor is when inserting the link, adding a class explicitly to the link. I don't want to rely on the content editors doing this though.

```
<div class="component link col-12">
    <div class="component-content">
      <div class="field-link">
        <a class="btn login-button" href="/ract" data-variantfieldname="Link" data-variantitemid="{33E5529D-270D-4738-9DCB-96DDB34EC23B}">Another</a>
      </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is my link field Css Class not appearing?  I have explicitly published to ensure that the markup isn't showing EE related markup.

Update: we are trying to use the bootstrap button styling of the link which is why I was trying to put it on the anchor element.

Comment: Am I right that `Tag` field on your variant definition item is empty? If you set it to `div` link will be wrapped with additional `div` with expected classes: `btn login-button` and `field-link`. This is how it works right now.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I was trying to put the classes on the anchor rather than on a containing div - but good to know thanks!

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I'm not sure the bootstrap styling will then apply to my link?  Or do I have to clone this rendering to override this behaviour?

Comment: CSS class on a parent element is not a problem in styling world. I would update CSS selector instead

Comment: Try to add class into data attributes section - add as "class" and {class name} approptiately - it works for me.

Comment: You can add class into "**Link attributes**" section "class" "class name".

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problems. This is how I tried to resolve it.

We have a checkbox for Is Link. So if you use it, we can use the data attributes and CSS class accordingly.