# Sitecore SXA redirect code functionality

Tags: sxa

I would like to add class name in redirect url anchor tag. Is it possible ??

Could someone let me know how redirect url create a anchor tag and where is the code of it?

[image]

Comment: Agree with @Marek's point here, could you please clarify why you need to add any class here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SXA redirects` should not be used normally for any links generation. Their purpose is completely different.

When you create a `this-url-should-be-redirected` redirect item and configure its `Redirection URL` to `some-another-link`, when someone tries to open `https://yourwebsite/this-url-should-be-redirected`, browser will redirect them to `https://yourwebsite/some-another-link`.

You can read more here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/redirect-a-url.html

Answer (score 0):

To add a class in an anchor tag, `Sitecore` provides you with the `OOTB` option to do this. So when you click on the insert link, you can find the option to add a class name

[image]

And if you want to do some customization then you have to create your own processor and then need to register this. To know more about this, you can follow these links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136867/sitecore-how-to-get-the-class-entered-in-general-link-field

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2015/10/10/add-a-custom-attribute-to-the-general-link-field-in-sitecore/

Comment: When I am adding in style class it is not showing in anchor tag which is created by redirects in experience editor .

Comment: I Added that using experience editor and the output is showing the class. 
<a href="/amazon/login" data-variantitemid="{C0B095E6-4F35-4208-8209-AAB9446A7BD7}" data-variantfieldname="Link" class="testclass">login</a></div>

So I have found one more thing for you. If you are using a rendering variant. Follow this article 

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/sxa-1-8-link-field-class-ignored-from-rendering-variant